# Add formoptions in (colspos and rowspos) in a hidden field in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid (Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.1.0) 
My field becomes hidden when I add formoptions.
The field is 'hidden:true' because I want it to show on the form and not on the grid. When I remove the formoptions, the field shows on the edit form and hides on the grid.

```
colModel: [
                   {
                label: 'First Name',
                name: 'fname',
                editable: true,
                hidden: true,
                 width: 200, 
                 editrules: {edithidden: true, required: true},
                 formoptions: {elmprefix:'(*)', colpos: 1, rowpos: 1 },

            },
```

Can someone have an Idea what i am not doing right?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the problem. This is a bug. The [problem is fixed in GitHub](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/ca1f55e6d603407cff5573e6f8ca28f4f98796ca) of Guriddo. Please check it.